# How to Delete Duplicates from a list of nodes in C?

Tags: c, nodes, duplicates

I have a following node which contains the duplicates, how can I get rid of the duplicates? The output it gives me is as follows. I am really new into this any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

a@ex.com b@ex.com b@ex.com c@ex.com d@ex.com e@ex.com e@ex.com f@ex.com

but I want

a@ex.com b@ex.com c@ex.com d@ex.com e@ex.com f@ex.com

//Node declaration.

```
Node tmpNodes[10];
typedef struct {
char emails[(LENGTH*2)+1];
}Node;
```

//Nodes are sorted using qsort().

```
qsort(tmpNodes, nodesCount, sizeof(Node), cmpFunc);

int cmpFunc(const void * userA, const void * userB){
Node * userAA;
Node * userBB;
userAA = (Node * )userA;
userBB = (Node * )userB;

return strcmp(userAA->emails, userBB->emails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By holding the first node, and discarding the following ones in the list that are the same as the held node.  When you find one that differs from the held node, it becomes the new held node.  Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: I am not sure how to approach that you have any example or something that might be helpful?

Comment: Well, you first need to figure out how to traverse the list.  Hint: use a `for` loop.  Everything follows from that.  The easiest way to make the new list is probably to... make a new list, rather than modifying the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

create new array, where you will copy nodes:

```
Node* tmpNodesUnique[10]; <-- NOTE it is pointers
int uniqueFound = 0;
tmpNodesUnique[0] = &tmpNodes[0];
for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    if (strcmp(tmpNodesUnique[uniqueFound]->emails, tmpNodes[i].emails) != 0)
        tmpNodesUnique[++uniqueFound] = &tmpNodes[i];
```

so, in uniqueFound - count if distinct emails will be stored, and tmpNodesUnique will contain pointers to unique nodes, so you can do something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<=uniqueFound; i++) <-- NOTE <=
    use tmpNodesUnique[i]->emails;
```